# Addition of elements of Two Arrays

Tags: arrays, multithreading, algorithm, language-agnostic, parallel-processing

You have Two arrays

```
int[] a = {......} // Total elements 1 million
int[] b = {......} // Total elements 1 million , Length is same for both arrays.
```

Q1. I have to create an array

```
int[] c
```

whose elements are sum of corresponding indexes of a[] and b []
Ex.

```
 c[0] = a[0] + b[0];
 c[1] = a[1] + b[1];
 c[2] = a[2] + b[2];
```

Solution : -> I can take advantage of Multithreading. Divide the whole array in 10 or more parts and assign each segment to a thread to perform the calculation.
Note-> Interviewer suggested to use Multithreading

Q2.
Now its little bit changed.Elements of array C will have values like this :->

```
c[0] = a[0] + b[0];
c[1] = a[1] + b[1] + c[0]; // At this line c[0] is Sum of a[0] + b[0]; The Above Line
c[2] = a[2] + b[2] + c[1]; // At this line c[0] is Sum of a[1] + b[1]+ a[0] + b[0]; The Above Line
```

MySolution-> Solve Part 1 (Q1) and create a temporary array and after that we have to perform addition like this.

```
C[1] = temp[1]+temp[0]
C[2] = temp[2]+temp[1]
```

Note :-> We really don't need temp[], we can do this only using  Array c Also. Just to explain this on SO in easy way.

Problem-> I dont think that in question 2 we can use multithreding. Is there a better way to solve Q2 ? Can we take advantage of multithreading in this.

Comment: [tag:C++], [tag:Java] or [tag:C]?

Comment: I guess the last operation can't be done using multi-threading, since the present index value depends on the last index value of array

Comment: @Mark Garcia Looks like Java by the array initialization.

Comment: @MarkGarcia In my view don't matter much, its parallel algo question.

Comment: Would multithreading even make part 1 or 2 faster?  Wouldn't the overhead outweigh the time gained from doing the calculations in parallel?

Comment: Q2 could be approached the way Grijesh Chauhan described, but wouldn't it take way more resources (by separating every element's calculations). In my opinion, sequential approach should be more than enough.

Comment: @shookees - These days parallel calculation should be applied whenever possible (which is the case we have). The major problem is that it requires a deep understanding of what you want to do, what you can do, and what you are actually doing.

Comment: @shookees actually this level of parallelism is good when we can core-access system (may be cuda)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do part 1 multi-threaded as you say giving -

```c
temp[0] = a[0] + b[0];
temp[1] = a[1] + b[1];
temp[2] = a[2] + b[2];
etc....
```

Then the calculation for part 2 becomes -

```c
c[0] = temp[0];
c[1] = temp[1] + temp[0];
c[2] = temp[2] + temp[1] + temp[0];
c[3] = temp[3] + temp[2] + temp[1] + temp[0];
etc...
```

Although this looks sequential and impossible to parallelize, it is in fact quite a common operation called a 'prefix sum' or 'scan'. For more details, including how to parallelize, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum) or [Blelloch](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~guyb/papers/Ble93.pdf).

In the 8 elements case this becomes the following where each recursive phase can be parallelized as each calculation has no dependency on other calculations in the same phase.

```c
// 1st phase 
u[0] = temp[0] + temp[1];
u[1] = temp[2] + temp[3];
u[2] = temp[4] + temp[5];
u[3] = temp[6] + temp[7];

// 2nd phase
v[0] = u[0] + u[1];
v[1] = u[2] + u[3];

// 3rd phase
w[0] = v[0] + v[1];

// final phase
c[0] = temp[0];
c[1] = u[0];
c[2] = u[0] + temp[2];
c[3] = v[0];
c[4] = v[0] + temp[4];
c[5] = v[0] + u[2];
c[6] = v[0] + u[2] + temp[6];
c[7] = w[0];
```

Comment: Just as a side note, avoid the `temp` array. You can calculate its values on the fly from the sums of the elements of `a` and `b`, and you will save writing and then reading a million elements (memory traffic is saved).

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion for question two you have two techniques:

First should be done in two steps. 
step-1 using threads you can add

```
 c[0] = a[0] + b[0];
 c[1] = a[1] + b[1];
 c[2] = a[2] + b[2];
```

as you suggested.

But step-2 should be done sequentially. because `c[ i + 1]` value depends on updated value of `c [i]`

Second technique is bit complex but can be fast.

What you are asked to do in second question is do something like:

```
 c[0] = a[0] + b[0];
 c[1] = a[1] + b[1] + a[0] + b[0];
 c[2] = a[2] + b[2] + a[1] + b[1] + a[0] + b[0];
```

This can be parallel.

```
c[i] =  thread1( sum(a[0]...a[i] )) + thread2( sum(b[0]...b[i] ))
         for i >= 0
```

Good is in this technique, you can calculate `c[i]` parallely for all `i` (its two like level threaded model).

You can further improve thread1/thread2 functions as multithread with child threads to perform sum – but remember sometime multi-threaded code runs slow then single-threaded code because of thread context-switching time (So you should give sufficient amount of task to each thread).

A point that is unlike about second technique is "most of what the threads for `c[i]` do is the same as what the threads for `c[i-1]` do as well".
Thanks to @[jogojapan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/777186/jogojapan) to let me know about this drawback point.

For better technique read updated [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17740295/addition-of-elements-of-two-arrays/17740526#17740526) by Mr.Jogojapan.

Comment: @ManishBhunwal Ok Good! Do have further question Manish? If you having  expert system in which you can access core (hard-threads) you we can improve it parallel at operation level (expression level).

Comment: Your second option will certainly keep all your processors busy. But in terms of algorithmic complexity, you've turned what used to be a sweet, linear little thing, into a grotesque, exponential monster. The two threads for the last element `c[n]` _alone_ perform as many operations (except storage) as the original linear algorithm did for _all_ elements combined.

Comment: @jogojapan keeping processors busy (= advantage of thread) so its good na **?**

Comment: Hmmm.. it's a good thing if they are mostly busy with stuff that the other threads are _not_ busy doing. But clearly, most of what the threads for `c[i]` do here is the same as what the threads for `c[i-1]` do as well.

Comment: Well, there is the general approach of Ian Cook's answer, and of course my own. But anyway... there is nothing bad about your answer. I just found it important to point out that it involves a lot of duplication of work.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you could use multithreading in this task. Your algorithm will consist in two parts:

1. apply Q1 algorithm - this part will use advantage of multithreading.
2. just in one-thred loop apply formyla: `c[n] = c[n] + c[n-1]`, `n=1...999999`.

Comment: @jogojapan read more carefully plz: in p.2 I said **one-thread** loop.

Comment: That doesn't really solve the problem then. We already knew that we can use multi-threading for Q1.

Comment: @jogojapan in question: **Problem-> I dont think that in question 2 we can use multithreding. Is there a better way to solve Q2 ?**. The answer: **use multithreading partially**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use multithreading here in the way from 1st question. I mean you can calculate

```
sumA0B0 = a[0] + b[0];
```

in separate threads and even wait for the calculation (sync ie on a[i]). Then in separate thread you can calculate  `c[i] = sumAiBi + c[i-1];`

Comment: "then, in a separate thread": Your use of "then" indicates that this happens _after_ the first step. And I guess it has to be that way, otherwise `sumAiBi` wouldn't be available. But if it's _after_, why use a separate thread at all?

Answer (score 0):

One way of using multi-threading for Q2 is to do it in two passes (each using T threads internally, where T can be chosen freely):

1. Compute `c[i] = a[i] + b[i] + c[i-1]` for all cells in the usual multi-threaded fashion, i.e. after dividing the input into ranges [0,r1), [r1,r2), ... [rk,n) and applying one thread to each range. Yes, this will be incorrect for all ranges except the first one, and step 2 will correct it.
2. Compute corrections, again in a multi-threaded fashion. For this, we look up the right-most value of each range, i.e. `corr1:=c[r1-1]`, `corr2:=corr1+c[r2-1]`, `corr3:=corr2+c[r3-1]` etc., which gives us the *correcting value* for each thread, and then calculate, again using multi-threading with the same ranges as before, `c[i] += corrk` where `corrk` is the thread-specific correcting value for the k-th thread. (For the zeroth thread, we can use `corr0:=0`, so that thread doesn't need to do anything.)

This improves the theoretical running time by a factor T where T is the number of threads (which can be chosen freely), so it's an optimal solution as far as multithreading is concerned.

---

To illustrate how this works, here is an example where we assume arrays of length `n==30`. We further assume that we use 3 threads: One to compute the range `c[0..9]`, one for `c[10..19]` and one for `c[20..29]`.

Clearly, the goal is that in cell `c[i]`, for any `0<i<n`, we get

```
c[i] == a[0]+...+a[i]+b[0]+...+b[i]
```

(i.e., the sum of all `a[0..i]` and all `b[0..i]`) after the algorithm has finished. Let's have a look at how the algorithm gets there, for an example cell `i==23`. This cell is handled by the third thread, i.e. the thread responsible for the range `c[20..29]`.

Step 1: The thread sets

```
c[20] = a[20]+b[20]
c[21] = c[20]+a[21]+b[21] == a[20]+a[21]+b[20]+b[21]
c[22] = c[21]+a[22]+b[22] == a[20]+a[21]+a[22]+b[20]+b[21]+b[22]
c[23] = c[22]+a[23]+b[23] == a[20]+a[21]+a[22]+a[23]+b[20]+b[21]+b[22]+b[23]
...
```

So, after step 1 has finished, we have the some of `a[20..23]` and `b[20..23]` in cell `c[23]`. What is missing, is the sum of `a[0..19]` and `b[0..19]`.

Similarly, the first and second threads have set the values in `c[0..9]` and `c[10..19]` such that

```
c[0] = a[0]+b[0]
c[1] = c[0]+a[1]+b[1] == a[0]+a[1]+b[0]+b[1]
...
c[9] = a[0]+...+a[9]+b[0]+...+b[9]
```

and

```
c[10] = a[10]+b[10]
...
c[19] = a[10]+...+a[19]+b[10]+...+b[19]
```

Step 2: The correcting value for the third thread, `corr2` is the sum of `corr1` and the right-most value computed by the second thread, while `corr1` is the right-most value computed by first thread. Hence

```
corr2 == c[9]+c[19] == (a[0]+...+a[9]+b[0]+...+b[9]) + (a[10]+...+a[19]+b[10]+...+b[19])
```

And this is indeed the sum missing from the value of `c[23]` after step 1. In step 2, we add this value to all elements `c[20..29]`, hence, after step 2 has finished, `c[23]` is correct  (and so are all other cells).

---

The reason why this works is that the calculation of the cell values is a left-to-right, strictly incremental operation, and the order of operations for the calcuation of a single cell doesn't matter (because `+` is associative and commutative). Hence the end-result ("right-most value") of any given thread after step 1 can be used to correct the results of threads responsible for the ranges to its right in step 2.

Comment: How will p.1 use multithreading? For every iteration you will need previously computed value of `c[i-1]`. It is not clear.

Comment: You didn't provide algorithm for computing this `thread-specific correcting value`. So you answer is not clear.

Comment: The thead-specific correcting value is the right-most value of the previous range. I'll explain....

Comment: Actually, I can't understand your idea. We will have to fix **ALL** values in `c` array in second part multiple times (not just though one multithread iteration). How it does differ from my solution in part of efficiency?

Comment: Yes, all values have to be corrected, but it can be done using any number of threads. Your solution uses just one thread.

Comment: @Andremoniy Note that the correcting value is different from your solution. In your solution, to correct `c[i]`, all `c[0]...c[i-1]` need to be added. But in my solution only `corrk` needs to be added, because the thread-local correction has already been made in the first step.

Comment: Well, actually in your algorithm you don't consider problems with synchronization and keeping copies of values into the memory for avoiding concurrent read/write operations onto it. Furthermore, you will have to do a lot of **one-thread** operations for computing these *correction* values.

Comment: @Andremoniy There are `T` correcting values, each takes O(1) time to compute. The overhead for that is of the same order as that for creating the threads in the first place, so that's negligible. And yes, after step 1 you need to wait until all threads of step 1 have finished (but if the ranges are equal in size, we can expect these threads to finish in roughly the same amount of time each).

Comment: I'm not talking about waiting of step-1 finishing. I'm talking about synchronization on corrected values, computed in each of step-2's thread. Generally speaking, it is not obvious and not provable that step-2 will be *real* multithreaded. If you could mathematically prove it (counting number of all **really** concurrent threads in each iteration of step-2) - I'll change my mind.

Comment: Why should you not be able to run them concurrently? They don't depend on each other.

Comment: + nice! it will take me some time to read, I didn't notice this answer first. I came here just for few minutes.

Comment: hey you answer is very good, if you need some ascii drawing to explain it you can use this [asci-flow](http://www.asciiflow.com/#Draw)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Cool, I didn't know that website. Maybe tomorrow; time to go to bed today.